# Can a DFA have multiple of the same state?

Tags: dfa

I need to create a DFA for a sequential order of states e.g. A -> B -> C -> B -> A
and so on, where 'A' is the start and finish state, 1 is a transition to the next state and 0 just loops back to the current state. 1 and 0 are the only inputs

Question below

1.1 You have been given the task to design the computational model for the traffic light
which operates with three colours, red (r), amber (a), and green (g). The sequential
flow of the traffic light is r → a → g → a → r and so on. Consider that the wait time
on each light is marked with the help of a binary, 0, and switching from one light to
another is marked by a binary 1. The wait on each light is optional and can continue
for any duration. If there is no input, the light remains red (r). If red (r) is considered
as your start and end point, and traffic lights must complete once cycle, then,

1.1.1 Draw a DFA which can accept this language considering the given workflow
in a continuous manner.

The only way I've found I can do it in this order is by having 2 B states, Is this ok or is there another way to do this?

Comment: If you have two semantically related states, you can always just call the second one "B-prime" or something, but make no mistake: they *are* two distinct states. Otherwise, it is no longer "Deterministic."

Comment: One of the B states is "B on the way to C" and the other is "B on the way to A". If you combined them into one state, then you wouldn't know which way to go next.

Comment: traffic lights don't transition from red to amber, nor from amber to green, at least not in America

Answer (score 1):

> Can a DFA have multiple of the same state?

A DFA state includes a list of condition that need to be satisfied to trigger a move to a different state (e.g. for state 2 you might have "If binary 1 is received, move to state 3" and "If reset button is pressed, move to state 1"). If the DFA state is the same then these trigger conditions must also be the same, which means that a duplicate state is redundant and trivially discarded.

However; the "outwardly observable" consequences of a state may be the same for different states. E.g. you can have 2 different states that both have the "amber light is on" consequences, but have different triggers and target states (e.g. "If binary 1 is received, **move to state 3**" vs. ""If binary 1 is received, **move to state 1**").

For fun; you could add a "walk/don't walk" light for pedestrians that's set to "walk" if the lights are red or "amber after red", and set to "don't walk" if the lights are green or "amber after green". Now you still have the same 4 states but there's an outwardly observable difference between all 4 states.

In a similar way, when entering each state you might set a different amount of time on the timer (e.g. "red for 35 seconds, amber for 5 seconds, green for 30 seconds, amber for 10 seconds").

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as Raymond Chen said above, 2 B states is this ok, there is no other way.